# Wildcard binding in Java does not binds to network aliases

Tags: java, linux, binding

I encountered a quite unusual issue, where the bind function to port only (i.e. wildcard bind), does not actually listens to Linux network aliases (the additional addresses on single network card).

This means that sending requests to main IP address for the network card does work normally, but any requests to additional IP's fails.

Have anyone encountered this in past?

Comment: How are these 'aliases' set up? `ip addr add`, or something else?

Comment: They added via ifcfg-eth0:0 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i do this:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.186/24 dev eth0
```

Then run this:

```
import java.net.*;

public class Bind {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888, 50, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("accepted socket " + s);
    }
}
```

Then, in another shell, this:

```
telnet 192.168.1.186 8888
```

The program in the first shell prints:

```
accepted socket Socket[addr=/192.168.1.186,port=33867,localport=8888]
```

If i repeat that but use my 'real' address, that works too.

So, it looks to me like binding to 0.0.0.0 binds to all addresses, including extra ones added to a device.

If i change the ServerSocket constructor call to use the single-argument form, everything still works as described, so it looks like that's binding to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Well, that might be an issue with Mina 1.1.x lib I have used, because in my case, UDP port simply works only on the first IP. Only after I specifically binded to each and every required IP, it started working normally.